# Dex merger issuse after upgrading library

Tags: android, gradle, realm, dex

after i upgrade library in the project
(realm from 4.2.0 to 4.3.1)
 to the latest version i got this error

```
error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: 
Error while merging dex archives: 
***build\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\android-
***build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar
.... 650 of build\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\....
```

allready tried to clean/build/reinstall/invalidate nothing work,
how to solve it?

Comment: This could be caused by conflicting dependencies. Could you post the entire error log and your `build.gradle` here?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerExceptionat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593) ...

Comment: Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.apache.commons.lang3.CharSetUtils

Comment: Please edit your question and post the error log and build.gradle file there if you still got the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into this bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5640#issuecomment-355497076

There is a workaround in the link and a fixed release is incoming.